# Facing design issues in jasper main and subreport reports

Tags: jasper-reports

i made main report having subreport.it's made right but facing design problem like:
main report have 2 column and subreport's  have 3-4 column so there are no proper design.
please give me any solutions.

Comment: Kindly post your design or xml. Without those, it is hard to help you out.

Comment: Here i can't send design,i can't able to upload any image.
so can you help me on other.